# robots.txt to remove searche engine results

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers

I heard you can remove google searches & images by adding something to robots.txt in main folder that the web directs to, how do I do that and how long does it take for the content to disapear?

Comment: you've heard that, but yet you were too lazy or incompetent to google for "robots.txt" ?

Comment: im sorry if this post offended you.. but I cannot see results directly as I understand crawling time takes some time to update, thats why I wanted to get help from people with experience so I dont have to wait 20+ hours just to see if something works. You have to relax abit mate

Comment: I don't think so. I really think this is a question that two minutes of google will solve better than 10 minutes of someone with the same (or less) knowledge than someone who wrote a documentation on robots.txt writing an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification mate, maybe next time I will go for your advice. But using degrading words is not appreciated tho

Comment: sorry, I did not mean to degrade you; please understand the sentence as encouragement that, given the fact that you heard of robots.txt, you should have applied your knowledge and researched yourself.

Comment: I did do that but I wanted to make sure that I was not on a wrong lead, wish you a good day sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

First line tells : Apply following to all the robots. 
Second line tells : Dont allow any page to be parsed.

Comment: Thanks mate, do you know how long it takes for it to be active? and does it remove old results?